# why yum update skipped 1000 package for dependency problems?

Tags: centos, yum, upgrade, dependencies

This morning I decided to update my Linux(CentOs 7.2.1511).but `yum` skip too many package because of dependency problem.

is it OK to proceed to update?! and why yum is skipping that so many packages?!

```
Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install                          4 Packages (+11 Dependent packages)
Upgrade                        160 Packages
Skipped (dependency problems)  941 Packages

Total download size: 195 M
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you've not updated the system for long days. Meantime CentOS 7.3 and CentOS 7.4 (current) has been released.

Some packages and libraries has been obsoleted in new system. To update `yum` need to remove them. But as your system is running based on those `yum` is failed to remove those packages.

**Solution** `dnf` can solve and skipe some dependency issues automatically. Install `dnf` as follows

```
sudo yum install dnf
```

If this fails with 'No Package found`install`dnf`from some`rpm`source. Google for 'dnf rpm download`, chose one for CentOS 7.x or RHEL 7. Then install it as follows

```
sudo rpm -Uvh path_to_downloaded_rpm
```

Then Update using `dnf` as follows
    sudo dnf update

Then clean as much unnecessary packages as possible using

```
sudo yum autoremove
sudo yum clean all
sudo dnf autoremove
sudo dnf clean all
```

Now again try to update using `yum`. You're likely to hit dependency problem again but with lesser number of package having issues. Then try to understand what those packages are and remove them one by one using `yum` or `dnf`.

**Warning** Please have a full backup before doing anything. It's very much likely that you'll face some issues during the process. Please update with error messages.